# SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

Why do I keep getting this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` in my code?

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) { 

    if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!"; 
    }

    else (numHours < 8 ) {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    };
}
console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

Comment: learn basic syntax no code allowed between  `else`  and `{`

Answer (score 3):

A `typo` error: Missing `if` after `else`[[`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)]

```js
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  } else if (numHours < 8) {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
  };
}
console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

**Note:** If you do not have any other condition, one do not really need `if(...)` part after `else` condition(As mentioned in comments)

```js
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  } else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
  };
}
console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

Comment: Really don't need the `if (numHours < 8)` part. Just the `else` (unless `numHours` is going to be `NaN`).

Comment: just `else` without any condition is enough ;)

Comment: @PranavCBalan – Nothing is equals to __`NaN`__ including `NaN` itself..

Comment: @Rayon : got it ;)

Comment: @PranavCBalan: All equality and relational operators return false if either argument is `NaN` -- `==`, `===`, `<`, `<=`, ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  } else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
  };
}
console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```